# How do I implement generic / package-agnostic logging for a Node.JS Project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, logging

I want to add logging to my Node.JS project, so that I can view debug logs while the application runs. There are a lot of different loggers out there for JavaScript apparently, and I'm not sure which one to use. Ideally, I would like to write my code so that the logger is not part of the codebase, but instead the logging is generic and I can switch between different generic logging libraries as I see fit. How can I do this?

Comment: i like to expose a function/method to log, something like `_LOG = IS_DEBUG ? console.log :  Boolean`, which runs quick and can be replaced by the user if desired.

Answer (score 0):

***Do not* use `Pino`, `debug`, or any other external loggers in your project if you intend for people to take a dependency on your package!**

#### abstract-logging: a no-op logging interface for JS modules.

You can use the NPM package [abstract-logging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abstract-logging) for these purposes. It implements a standard log4j logging interface of no-ops. From the readme:

> This module provides an interface for modules to include so that they
> can support logging via an external logger that conforms to the
> standard Log4j interface. One such logger is Pino. This module is
> intended for modules that are meant to be used by other modules.

This way, when you release your package, you only have to include the small, no dependency library as a direct dependency. Libraries like `Pino`, `debug`, etc. can be included as dev-dependencies while working on the package, and when someone takes a dependency on your package they don't have to worry about having their logging library clashing with your logging library, causing all sorts of debug troubles.